# Click through elements phonegap

Tags: html, cordova

I am using phonegap to build an application. On the page, there are a `link A` and a `div`. Take a look at the illustrative picture.

[image]

The `div` overlaps the `link`, we cannot see the link. But if I click on the the `div` at the location of the `link`, a click event fired on the link. Is this a phonegap bug? How to resolve it?

Comment: Can you please rewrite it, i don't really understand what you want.

Comment: how are you sure that the dialog overlaps the link A? Have you tried giving different background colors to the `link` element and the `dialog` element to be sure that the `dialog` **overlaps** the `link` element

Comment: @Seb1929T: I have rewritten it, hope you understand what i mean. @frank: I am sure that the `dialog` overlaps the `link`. The background color of the dialog is solid, we cannot see the link. On computer browser, everythings is ok. On android app, i can click through the dialog.

Comment: Found a similar bug. Also if ONE LINK IS ABOVE EACH OTHER both are clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I've been banging my head around this for a while...

**The problem is not phonegap, it's the jquery mobile's VCLICK-event** See the yellow warning here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/

> Webkit based browsers synthesize mousedown, mouseup, and click events
>   roughly 300ms after the touchend event is dispatched.

I suppose, you handle the "vclick", then in 300ms the overlapping DIV disappears and the "click" is passed to the LINK.

**Solution** Simply don't use the 'vclick' event on overlapping elements. Or when the DOM is being modified (and becomes different in 300ms)